# Proper continuous integration and continuous deployment with Git and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, continuous-integration, heroku, continuous-deployment

I am developing a ruby on rails website using heroku and git.

What tools and features should I use to set up the following simple development process?

CODE > CHECK-IN > AUTO TEST > AUTO DEPLOY

- I check my code into my repository (preferred option, hosted git like github)
- Tests are automatically run AND website is deployed in my staging heroku app
- If tests pass, the website is automatically deployed on my production heroku app
- If tests fail, I want to be notified somehow.

How would you do this?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend auto-deployment, since you pretty sure will commit half-ready features, that shouldn't go live directly.

Comment: +1 on not doing this in production - very dangerous to have you app auto deploy that way. Deploying to a staging server would be fine though.

Comment: ^^^ That kind of defeats the purpose of continuous deployment doesnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Integrity](http://integrityapp.com/). It is a pretty simple solution - it won't do everything under the sun, but it's quite easy to set up and handles the most common use cases/features. It's also pretty easy to hack on, if you want it to do more.

Integrity states:

> Heroku is the easiest and fastest way to deploy Integrity.

However:

> NOTE
>   It isn’t possible to access repositories over SSH on Heroku

This is because your Integrity app will need an SSH key. It's not impossible, but definitely a few hoops to jump through. You'll need to give Integrity a private key and put it in the app, and then hack Integrity to use that ssh key when it initiates the `git clone`.

Of the things you listed, the automatic deploy is probably the thing most people would not expect their CI server to do (and Integrity does not provide out of the box). You'll need to configure git to use that ssh key and initiate a `git push` from the proper location (the checked out repository).

Unfortunately I don't know the details of how to do this--we actually run Integrity on a VPS.

Comment: Seems like Integrity site is down, are they out of business?  Their DNS expired or something.?

Comment: The domain is kaput.

Answer (score 5):

[CircleCi](https://circleci.com) offers exactly what you need. We'll run your tests on every push, deploy them if they pass (to Heroku or using Capistrano/Fabric/anything really), and send you notifications if they fail.

Answer (score 2):

to preface I am one of the founders of Codeship (https://codeship.io), which is a service that supports exactly this.

But more on topic, basically there are 2 different ways I think this could be implemented (please keep in mind that all branch names I use are arbitrary and can be named totally different):

### staging/production in one go

Whenever you push to your master or a specific deploy branch you run your tests and if all of them pass you first deploy to your staging app, run separate tests (Selenium or sauce labs is great for that) and if that works out including migrations you push to your production app.

This is great as the latest version is always available in production and we use this cycle for a long time now. Works great for us. The downside is that pushing to a staging heroku app takes some time. If you want to run the migrations against a copy of your production data this takes even more time. It's not an eternity, but it takes a couple of minutes.

### staging/production as separate steps

You could have separate staging/production branches which are deployed to the respective heroku applications. This has the advantage of being faster and you can control when to release certain parts. Especially for applications where you want external feedback before deploying to production this works great.

We support all of that at Railsonfire, but we are currently working on a new version of our service which is way better. We integrate really well with Heroku so you don't have to think about that (but still have the option to do it yourself in any way you want)

Comment: This reads a bit too much like an advertising "call to action" to be appropriate as an answer here.

Comment: Sorry @AndrewBarber if this came over a little to advertisy, but I wanted to address a few different ways how to do continuous deployment effectively. 

I thought that as he specifically asked for hosted providers (he did so below with Hudson) telling him a little about our service might be ok.

Comment: I would definitely get rid of all the stuff related to your contact information; that's what pushes it from questionable to well over-the-top, in my opinion. I don't think you are intending to 'spam', and you're a new user here, so I'm not flagging anything now. I'll do some edits that I think fix *this post itself*, but I would also recommend reading the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for more general guidance, too.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools in the market that do this. [SnapCI](https://snap-ci.com) offers [deployment pipelines](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DeploymentPipeline.html) that let you push every commit through tests and then subsequently into staging and production as different stages of a deployment pipeline. We also have full support for test parallelization, building branches and pull-requests.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is Hudson which provides a git plugin as well as scripting support. The rest is configuration, I would guess.

Hudson: http://hudson.dev.java.net

Comment: Can you recommend any hosted hudson provider?

Comment: No, I don't think there is some kind of hudson hosting, but it is easy to setup and configure. You could even run it on your developer box.

Comment: CloudBees offers Jenkins (Which is the evolution of Hudson). They also offer a Free tier.
http://www.cloudbees.com/jenkins-enterprise-by-cloudbees.cb

Answer (score 0):

Try [Heroku-Bartender](https://github.com/sarcilav/heroku-bartender). A write-up [here](http://code.dblock.org/ShowPost.aspx?id=186).