# Continuous Integration Server for Heroku RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, continuous-integration

We need CI on Heroku for our RoR app.

We want to use an add-on.  I don't mind paying a few bucks to avoid complexity / distraction.

I see its basically Railsonfire vs. Tddium

What are the factors that we should consider in choosing to use one vs. the other?

A similar question was asked at the link below, but it appears that this was before the add-ons above were created.
[Proper continuous integration and continuous deployment with Git and Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127194/proper-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-with-git-and-heroku)

Comment: I see no need for a heroku add-on. Never really dug the differences but I use semaphoreapp which works as expected

Comment: A few questions you might wanna ask yourself: how fast is your build? how long does it take your test suite to run? How often you check-in code? How many devs you have on your team that check in code?

Comment: Thank you both.  @apneadiving - perhaps there is no benefit to having an add-on.  That is good to know as well.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is [CircleCi](https://circleci.com), which makes it incredibly easy, though it isn't yet in the Heroku add-on marketplace.

I personally believe speed is the major consideration. The speed at which your team moves is tied to how quickly you can get notifications, and a platform optimized for speed is going to make a major difference.

In addition, on slow platforms, tests may fail randomly (for example, Cucumber might fail if a button doesn't appear in 3 seconds, which may not happen soon enough on a slow platform).

I'm a founder of [CircleCi](https://circleci.com), and we make an incredibly fast CI solution (faster than both services you mentioned). It's really easy to set up (one-click), though it's not in the Heroku marketplace (yet).

Comment: I personally use CircleCI, we have found it to be very good. No problems setting up CD with Opsworks on AWS either it allows a huge amount of customisation. Also very fast and will scale with long term growth. All configured with a handy YAML file a checkout from a Git repo and your away laughing.

Answer (score 1):

One consideration I'd give you to… uh… consider is support. I don't know anything about the Tddium team, but I do know that a couple months ago I tried Rails On Fire was blown away by the support. I asked some crazy questions (I do crazy things) and Florian responded in email and on Twitter right away with both help and suggestions.

Then, when I decided not to use the service because it couldn't support one edge-case feature, he implemented the feature! I hadn't been using it for a couple weeks and he wrote back to me personally to say "Hey, we finally got that feature you thought would be helpful."

I've used Hudson/Jenkins for years and know what you mean about complexity. But I also think that having someone on the other end is pretty key, and the RailsOnFire team, for now at least, do that quite well.